# Detect a property being assigned with the same value twice with ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, typescript

So basically I have an array of objects and I want to give the index of a selected object in the array to another component through `@Input`.

The problem is, when selecting the same item twice the `ngOnChanges` function doesn't detect a change since it doesn't recognize it as a change when I set the value from 1 to 1... This results in me not being able to select the same object twice in a row.

Child Component:

```js
@Input('editAppointmentIndex') editAppointmentIndex: number;


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    if (changes.editAppointmentIndex && changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue != undefined) {
      // Do what i want to do with the selected object
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```html
<child-component [editAppointmentIndex]="currentAppointmentIndex"></child-component>
```

```js
currentAppointmentIndex: number;

onEdit(i) {
    this.currentAppointmentIndex = i;
}
```

Sibling Component:

```html
<button class="edit" (click)="onEdit(i)">Edit</button>
```

```js
@Output() onEdit_: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

onEdit(i) {
    this.onEdit_.emit(i);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve], you are talking about an object, but you have defined `editAppointmentIndex` to be a number?

Comment: @AJT_82 Sry im new to stack overflow, give me a second

I defined it as a number because i only pass the indexnumber of the object in the array

Comment: @AJT_82 Hope this is enough

Comment: Yes, that is perfect :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the number stays the same, it isn't a new value, and thus `OnChanges` does not fire.

I don't find it too inconvenient to pass an object with the index to resolve this issue. So I suggest the following:

```
editAppointmentIndex = {};

onEdit(i) {
  this.editAppointmentIndex = { index: i };
}
```

Then you would get the index with:

```
if (changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue && changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue.index != undefined) {
  console.log(this.editAppointmentIndex.index)
}
```

DEMO: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvgl8n)**

Comment: It tells me Type Error: "changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue is undefined", how do i fix this?

Comment: it should be `if (changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue && changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue.index != undefined) `

Comment: @Reza Should work without the first if, since we have intialized `editAppointmentIndex` (see demo), but thinking further, we can add that first check just in case :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick help and replies, it works fine now <3

Comment: @AJT_82 changes.editAppointmentIndex.currentValue is not same as editAppointmentIndex as far as I know, for example if biding become null the for sure, currentValue is null

Comment: @Reza Good point, the value can become null, I changed the answer according to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the @Input with a setter

```
oldValue:number;
@Input()
set editAppointmentIndex(value: number) {
  if (value&&value!=this.oldValue) {
  // Do what i want to do with the selected object
  }   
 this.oldValue = value;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7su2kw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You example works. open the f12 console. set fired is outputted every time you switch between the name1 and name2. Not when you press on the same twice. I use firefox

Comment: The point is that OP wants ngOnChanges to fire **even when the value is the same** as the previous value, and we can see in the demo that the setter is not fired when same value is clicked.

Comment: @JensAlenius, yes, even though at first sight it look like it works, but your solution doesn't work, so when the value is set to same again, set doesn't happen

Comment: The solution with the object above (AJT_82) works with the setter