# angular - blur event not resetting value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, blur, ngonchanges

I have a search bar functionality where I use `ngOnChanges` to detect the search term change, enabling me to filter through some data. However, if I use the previous search term value again, this change will not be caught. Now I know this makes sense because, effectively, there was no change to the search term property.

It seems when I use the 'x' clear button in the search bar, I can use the same search term once again. However, it's not working if I am to remove focus from the search bar and then try to repeat the search term.

My .ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders-list',
    templateUrl: './orders-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders-list.component.css'],
})
export class OrdersListComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit{
    
    @Input() searchTerm: string; // <----

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        // searchTerm comes from parent component, if it changes then a new search is active
        // want to detect when the current value equals previous value
        if (changes.searchTerm) {
            if(changes.searchTerm.currentValue === "") {
                /* do stuff */
            }
            else{
                /* do stuff */
            }
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

The search bar .ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './orders-toolbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders-toolbar.component.css'],
})
export class OrdersToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;
    @Output() searchTerm = new EventEmitter<string>();
    @Output() isSearchActive = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    hideSearchBar: boolean;
    searchString: string;
    searchStringUpdate = new Subject<string>();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchString = "";
        this.hideSearchBar = true;
        this.searchStringUpdate.pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged())
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.onSearchChange();
            }
        );
    }

    resetSearchBar() {
        this.searchString = "";
        this.onSearchChange();
        this.hideSearchBar = true;
        this.onSearchBarContext(false);
    }

    showSearchBar() {
        this.searchInput.nativeElement.focus();
        this.hideSearchBar = false;
        this.onSearchBarContext(true);
    }

    onSearchChange() {
        this.searchTerm.emit(this.searchString);
    }

    onSearchBarContext(isActive: boolean){
        this.isSearchActive.emit(isActive);
    }

    clearSearch(){
        this.searchString = "";
        this.onSearchChange();
    }
}
```

And for the search bar .html:

```
<div id="search" class="hide-searchbar" [ngClass]="{'show-searchbar': this.hideSearchBar === false}">
    <input
        id="searchbar"
        type="search"
        autocomplete="off"
        [(ngModel)]="searchString"
        (ngModelChange)="this.searchStringUpdate.next($event)"
        (blur)="resetSearchBar()"
        (search)="clearSearch()"
        (keydown.escape)="searchInput.blur()"
        #searchInput
    />
</div>
...
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just like there being `currentValue`, I think there is another property called `previousValue`. Could that help?

Comment: @AliF50 Yeah, but the issue is that it doesn't go into `if (changes.searchTerm)`  in the first place if `currentValue === previousValue`.  Since I can't detect the change I can't apply the logic. Awkward situation.

Comment: I see. Can you remove that `if`?

Comment: @AliF50 I've tried it but it isn't triggered. It doesn't even go inside `ngOnChages` whatsoever.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557429/7365461 I think you can use a `setter` on the `input` instead of worry about it on the `ngOnChanges`. This way you should get notified even if the values are the same.

Comment: @AliF50 Still not working believe it or not.  I've noticed this only happens when I remove focus from the search bar. When I press the clear 'x' button in the search bar it allows me to repeat the search term value. I'll post the search bar code. Tell me if you see something I don't.

Comment: Where is the `[searchTerm]="..."` in the HTML? And this issue is strange where `blur` behaves differently than `x`. Are you sure `resetSearchBar` gets called?

Comment: @AliF50 `resetSearchBar` is being called indeed. The search term is emitted to the parent component    like so : 
`onSearchInserted(searchTerm: string){
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
}`. 
This `searchTerm` is then sent to the child `OrdersListComponent` through data binding.

Comment: @AliF50 Parent has `(searchTerm)="onSearchInserted($event)"` (emitted from search bar component). And then has `[searchTerm]="searchTerm"` (sent to the component in my question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[searchTerm]="searchString"`?

Comment: @AliF50 It works the way it is. It only doesn't work when I blur and use the same search value as the previous one. When I blur the search bar and use a different input it works, lol. This is so weird.

Comment: @AliF50 Finally managed to [solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679778/15822615). I appreciate your help nonetheless.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `distinctUntilChanged` operator from the subscription inside `ngOnInit` did the trick.

Like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchString = "";
    this.hideSearchBar = true;
    this.searchStringUpdate.pipe(
        debounceTime(500))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.onSearchChange();
        }
    );
}
```

As the name would suggest, `distinctUntilChanged` [only emits when the current value is different than the last.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)